# primefaces calendar pages: show last, this, next month

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

If setting up primefaces (6.0) calendar displaying tree pages, the current month relative to *value* and the two following are shown:

```
<p:calendar
  ...
  mode = "popup"  <!-- default -->
  pages = "3" />
```

**How to show the last, current and next month?**

It's not mindate, maxdate, because other months have to stay selectable.

Did I miss something when using ecosia, google, stackoverflow and primefaces showcase/doc?

Comment: Hello did you found solution for this problem ?

Comment: No, sorry, did not ...

Answer (score 0):

Met the same problem recently. I know what jQuery calendar has an attribute 'setCurrentAtPos' which is responsible for the position of the current month (in case of several months), but I could not use it in the primafeces calendar.

Instead of that, I used js for click 'prev' button when div with months is showing up:

```
<script> 
        var aligned = false;

        function alignCurrentMonth(){
            if(!window.aligned) {
                $('.ui-datepicker-prev').click()
                window.aligned = true;
            }
        }

        function setNotAligned(){
            window.aligned = false;
        }
</script>
```

and

```
<p:calendar id="calendar_date"
            value="#{cc.attrs.dates.selected}"
            mask="true"
            locale="en_US"
            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"                    
            pages="3"
            onclick="alignCurrentMonth()"
            onblur="setNotAligned()"                    
            disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}">                
</p:calendar>
```